# How should I add the months of work experience on my resume?

Tags: resume, new-job, job-change, applications, job-description

If I worked at a company from 1 June to 10 Aug, and the online application just has a field for months, am I supposed to include Aug in the months or leave it because it was not  even half a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself: *Does it really matter?*

You have not specified the staring and ending year, assuming the same year, we can say you were there for 2+ months.

Is there anything that significant that you achieved in those last 10 days, which will have an impact you you count those days less? Likely, the answer is no.

On the other hand, what will be the problem if you count those 10 days and mention you were there up to August?

Go ahead and mark whatever you feel correct. It's a borderline change that mostly no one will be caring about, if you have the documents showing the claims you make.

*If I were you, I'd choose to mark August, since, I would have drawn the salary (partial) for that month.*